# Networkx error :" in _not_implemented_for terms = {'directed': graph.is_directed()}"

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to implement some clustering problem, however I meet following problem: 
error imformtionis here is here:

```
File "/Users/shaoyupei/Desktop/project ", line 99, in <module>
c=new_clustering(H,list_)

File "/Users/shaoyupei/Desktop/project ", line 83, in new_clustering
c = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)

File "<decorator-gen-232>", line 2, in connected_component_subgraphs

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-      packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in _not_implemented_for
terms = {'directed': graph.is_directed(),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_directed'
```

The things code do is here: input a graph ,and the edge list with weighted, repeat to move the first element in the edge list until the  partition is appearing 
here is the the form of input list :

`list_=[(('name', 'year'), 0.9), (('aunt', 'work'), 0.5173567819580527), (('family', 'world'), 0.5154954800891427), (('aunt', 'moment'), 0.5096782251214088), (('full', 'glad'), 0.5080586691030745), (('bed', 'miserable'), 0.5074225221081745), (('miserable', 'name'), 0.5074225221081745) ...]`

and here is the code:

```
def new_clustering(G,_list):
  c= nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G) # postion1
  c =list(c)
  l= len(c)
  l2=-1
  while (l2 < l+1):
      e = _list.pop(0)[0]
      G = G.remove_edge(*e)
      c = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G) #postion2
      c = list(c)
      l2= len(c)

  return c

H= H.to_undirected()
k=new_clustering(H,list_)
```

here is what things happens, I know 
  `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)` is only implement for undirected graph, however the error do not raising in `postion1` of code , and I move the edge successfully , but the it happens at the first iteration of `position2` , how come it happens?

Comment: what is `list_` in the last line of your code?  Where is it defined, and what is its value?   I have the same questions for `H`.  It looks to me like `H` is `None`, causing `G` to be `None`  in your function.

Comment: @Joel  `list_ is list of python in this form ,[(('name', 'year'), 0.9), (('aunt', 'work'), 0.5173567819580527) ....]`, H is not none  in the function I have been tested, and is complete at beginnning, , the problem I most confuse is why this issue occur when one edge is got removed ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `G = G.remove_edge(*e)`.

`G.remove_edge` modifies `G` "in place".  That is, it directly removes the edge from `G`.  It doesn't return a new graph that looks like `G` with the edge removed.  So when you do `G = G.remove_edge(*e)`, you are removing the edge from `G` and then creating a new variable `G` which is whatever gets returned from `G.remove_edge(*e)`.  But nothing is returned.  So `G` has now become `None`.

Here's an example:

```
import networkx as nx
G= nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
print(G.edges())
> [(1, 2)]
A=G.remove_edge(1,2)  #it's removing the edge directly from `G` and assigning the returned value to be `A`.
print(G.edges())  #no edges,
> []
print(A)  #since `G.remove_edge` doesn't return anything, this is None
> None
```